# What was Gandalf's plan for getting the Ring to Mount Doom?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I'm currently re-reading *The Lord of the Rings* for the umpteenth time, and a question occurred to me.

When Gandalf hears from Faramir that Frodo and Sam were heading for Cirith Ungol, he is shocked. Obviously, he hadn't planned to take them that way if he had survived Moria. So, what *was* his plan? We know he couldn't have got into Mordor via the Morannon. Is there any clue anywhere of the route he had been planning to take to get to Mount Doom?

Comment: i remember something about a dragon fire can also destroy the ring.

Comment: He plans to simply walk into Mordor.

Comment: @Itay Moav - Gandalf explained to Frodo that not even the fire of Ancalagon the Black can destroy the One Ring.

Comment: @Rex Kerr  - Yep, thought I remember something with Dragon fire. Just not the important detail

Comment: Note the Morannon and Cirith Ungol are not the only ways into Mordor. The Morgul / Nameless Pass is the main alternate route to the Morannon, Cirith Ungol is just close by. 

"Far up the northern wall of the Morgul Pass, far above the main roadway, was a steep secondary pass reached by a perilous stairway, and known as Cirith Ungol." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_places_in_Middle-earth#M

Comment: Perhaps the safest route of all would have been to hike east around the Ered Lithui and then circle back west and thus enter Mordor from the east.

Comment: They went through Caradhras and then Moria because bypassing Saruman to get to Minas Tirith would take too long.  I assume this roundabout way would rejected for the same reason.

Comment: His plan was clearly to use the Eagles all along.  They were just napping up until he had to fight a Balrog.

Comment: @Jeff "One Does Not Simply Walk Into Mordor" ;) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r21CMDyPuGo)

Comment: Is Gandalf really "shocked"by that news?He more than anyone would realize Cirith Ungol would be a logical decision

Comment: @RobertF That would have taken them too close to Barad-dur, to my mind anyway.

Comment: @RobertF That would be safest for the Ringbearer certainly, but they things worked out, they didn't have nearly enough supplies to go that out of their way.  It is questionable if that would have been much different with Gandalf still around.  There is also the issue of how much more damage Sauron would have done if they took the time to do that.

Comment: "Do I really look like a guy with a plan, Frodo? You know what I am? I'm a dog chasing cars. I wouldn't know what to do with one if I caught it! You know, I just... *do* things." —[Dumbledore](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/es.starwars/images/4/4e/ObiWanHS-SWE.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120125222904)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As others have already answered, there was no distinct plan other than to send the ring off towards Mordor in hopes of destroying it.  Elrond specifically calls this out and suggests that the lack of a plan is a virtue in and of itself:

> I think that this task is appointed for you, Frodo; and that if you do not find a way, no one will. This is the hour of the Shire-folk, when they arise from their quiet fields to shake the towers and counsels of the Great. Who of all the Wise could have foreseen it? Or, if they are wise, why should they expect to know it, until the hour has struck?

Before the fellowship departs he cautions:

> Look not too far ahead!

The Plan, espoused by the Wise is to not hold too dearly to any one course of action.  A loosely formulated plan allows the hand of Providence to play a role in its success.  Boromir provides an example of a specific plan, influenced by ideology and carried out by force of will, that goes astray.  Boromir's singular goal is to bring the ring to Gondor, unable to deviate from this plan he uses coercion and force to further his plan and ultimately is tempted by the Ring to attack Frodo.

Evil, in *The Lord of the Rings* is often characterized as unyielding uniformity, a Plan; while Good is aligned with natural and organic processes that deal with change rather than trying to control it. So Gandalf's plan allows events to unfold naturally without the domination of his, or anyone else's will.

Comment: So... Elrond basically said, "Eh, just wing it."

Comment: @Steam: And if Boromir complained Elrond could tell him "Hey, it worked for Earendil... "

Comment: @Steam Yes, Elrond basically said that. Which isn't all that smart in my opinion. It's one thing for the Wise to say a plan must be flexible, and that the Fellowship must be ready to think on their feet, but a completely different thing to have _no plan at all_. "Here, take these guns. Go take Berlin. How? I don't know, I'm sure you'll figure it out. Do not think ahead." :P

Comment: Elrond had already messed up his try at getting rid of the Ring.

Comment: @Steam: Keep in mind that we're not talking "realistic fiction" here; we're inside an epic story, and Elrond realizes it's an epic - and there are certain ways in which one acts if one is in an epic. Making detailed plans is not one; perhaps too he realizes that (just as the ownership of the ring by Bilbo and Frodo shows the influence of Iluvatar) much must be left up to Iluvatar. "God will provide, my son."

Comment: We're also talking a small task force of experts, rather than the storming of Normandy.  While a large task like the latter would require a very carefully thought out plan to make sure it doesn't go astray, the smaller group could presumably come up with a plan that would work out in the end.

Comment: Zibbobz: I agree, it wasn't so much "Go take Berlin" as "Go kill Hitler", (continuing the metaphor) a few men can gather intel and infiltrate a secure compound. An invasion force needs to be aimed (see planned) very carefully, you pull the trigger and days, weeks or months later it goes "bang". A small force acting on it's own initiative is far more flexible and difficult for the enemy to spot. Ergo I think the "just wing it" non-plan is sound.

Comment: Although this is somewhat beside the original point, I'd like to point to events like [The Children's Crusade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Crusade), where thousands went and quite literally expected the sea to part before them. Talk about that as "something will come up"...

Comment: While it's fair to characterize the plan as "Just wing it!", it may be relevant to note that the plan *worked*. (There's a joke where one economist says to the other, "It may work in practice, but does it work in theory?") Though I wouldn't recommend this approach for everyday use in an universe like ours where Providence seems to take a more subtle approach.

Answer (score 27):

> Aragorn was of the opinion that Gandalf didn't have a specific plan beyond Lórien - he was intending to talk to Galadriel and possibly take a gander in her mirror, and see if he could cook up a plan on the way.
>
> <sub>Source: [TVTropes:TheLordOfTheRings:Headscratchers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/TheLordOfTheRings)</sub>

That same page has a couple of other theories but none seem to stem from the source material.

To clarify, the statement above is based on first page of Chapter 8 of Book Two (hat tip Kate Ebneter):

> "We have not decided our course," said Aragorn. "Beyond Lothlórien I do not know what Gandalf intended to do. Indeed I do not think that even he had any clear purpose."

Comment: How is that a reliable source? It's just people riffing about problems they had with the books.

Comment: @Mark - I fail to find any place in my answer where I stated it was a **reliable** source. However, the quote does sound like it's made on the basis of SOME material ("Aragorn was of the opinion", not "I think"). Could be mis-wording on the part of whoever posted this, or could be based on actual source data.

Comment: The part about "intending to talk to Galadriel" etc. is inferred, but the part about Aragorn thinking Gandalf had no plan past Lothlorien is straight out of the first page of Chapter 8 of Book Two: "'We have not decided our course,' said Aragorn. 'Beyond Lothlorien I do not know what Gandalf intended to do. Indeed I do not think that even he had any clear purpose.'"

Comment: @Kate - I'll add the quote to the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 6):

I have always considered - largely based on the quote from Aragorn - that Gandalf had no ideas and no plans beyond Lothlórien. I think the evidence suggests that he rarely had any clear and decisive plans about **how** to do things, even though he had clear plans about **what had to be achieved**. He had very clear plan to take the ring to Mordor and destroy it in the Cracks of Doom, but exactly how this was going to be achieved in practice, I doubt he really knew.

I suspect that he may have had some idea not unlike the one he finally carried out, to take a force up to the main gate, distract Sauron, and hope the hobbits could sneak in. But I am sure it was not clearly thought out. He strikes me as more a big picture person that a details person.

Comment: TL;DR: Gandalf was Senior Management. His was to Set High Goals, not worry about implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Frodo and Sam could have easily crossed over into Mordor from South Ithilien via the pass at the source of the River Poros. OTOH, they would need to have crossed at least double the distance through the deserts of Mordor. But this would not have been insurmountable since the distance from Cirith Ungol was crossed with only one skin of water with only a couple of refills. If they hadn't gone up the Morgul Vale, they would have had 2 water skins available.

Comment: That would have been a huge detour. Do you have any indication that this pass would have been easier/safer than the Black Gate or Cirith Ungol?

Answer (score 0):

Gandalf does indeed have a plan for getting into Mordor, he just isn't consciously aware that that's what his plan is *for*.  Gandalf's plan, as expressed to Frodo in the 'many that die deserve life' speech in Moria, is this: *keep Gollum alive*.  Gandalf knows, or at least strongly suspects, that this will achieve *something* ('some part to play yet, for good or ill, before the end'), although he doesn't know that one of the particular things it will achieve is finding a route into Mordor.

Answer (score -2):

I will try to keep my answer very short.

Firstly, this is an epic story and fictional, the characters play the writers song. So yea, Gandalf’s plans are unknown because Tolkien, as far as I know, never put down all his alternative ideas for the *Lord of the Rings*, like the plan for the Community of the ring. That will be kept a mystery forever unless his son, Christopher discovers some papers in which appear some possible ideas for the Community’s roads.

Secondly, yea if I were Gandalf, I would have also planned something like the eagle plan. I would have asked Radagast, when Saruman uses him to lure Gandalf into Orthanc, to send some friends “eagles” to go around spying the Enemy and also to get them ready and prepared to come into Lórien, when the time comes, or having at least one eagle messenger (Gwaihir) flying between Lórien and the eagles nests. If you remember after defeating the Balrog at the top of Zirakzigil Gandalf arrives into Lórien with Gwaihir’s help.

So yeah the eagle plan theory basics are totally possible and are correct for me. But don’t use the wrong ideas from the films “butterfly”, like Gandalf casting the eagle spell so freely and cheaply.

And lastly, we should already know that the eagles always appear in key points around Gandalf, when he is in total peril and nothing else could have been written that would have either way broken the logic of the Third Age marc. I don’t want to see for example a Valar saving the day, although the eagles are like sons of Manwë.

Tolkien put the eagles and their home on the Misty Mountains, that’s all.